# Make div top two divs fixed after some scroll and reset back when scrolled to top again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i am trying to make a div remain fixed after some scroll in parent div?

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="fw ofndr-box">
      <div class="ofndr-box-half add-here">
        <a href="#!/lead-court/5c0622ad78bdba5f566538d8" style="color: white;">Header 1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ofndr-box-half2 add-here">
        <a href="#" data-ng-click="addrequestpopup()" class="ofndr-btn pull-right">+New</a>
      </div>
      <div class="fw ofndr-box-in">
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is my working fiddle i want to fix header and +new button after scroll of blue colored div.
https://jsfiddle.net/pavansn/tvg3d709/1/

Comment: `position:fixed`.....?

Answer (score 0):

As your scroll is on `ofndr-box` instead of `window` so in Js you can try

`var scroll = $('.ofndr-box').scrollTop();`

and change :

`$(".add-here").addClass(".fixed"); to $(".add-here").addClass("fixed");`